# Extract a numerical value from text

Tags: r

I have text files that contain the following line (or similar):

> 178487\ASF=-873.1421319\NFGH=540.56201\PG=C01

How would I extract the values after `ASF=` using R?

I have already started with:

---

```
library(stringr)
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(file_list)) {
  mydataFrame = readLines(file_list[i])
  value1 <- grep("ASF=", mydataFrame, value = TRUE)
  value2 <- as.numeric(str_extract(value1,"[0-9]+$"))  

  }
```

Comment: What is your desired output exactly?

Comment: -873.1421319
Thx

Answer (score 2):

You would like to extract `-873.1421319` that follows `\ASF=`,
for example from the string: `178487\ASF=-873.1421319\NFGH=540.56201\PG=C01`

The pattern `[0-9]+$` you used is incorrect, for many reasons:

- `$` matches the end of the string. This pattern would match `01` in the example string, as that is the numeric sequence at the end of it.
- The pattern `[0-9]+` will match a non-empty sequence of digits. It will not include `-` and `.`.

So you need to drop the `$`, and improve the pattern to account for the `-` and `.`, for example: `-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?`.

However, this is still enough,
because you only want the number following `\ASF=`,
but without including `\ASF=` itself inside the match.
To do that, you need to use a positive lookbehind:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(s, '(?<=\\\\ASF=)-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
for (i in 1:length(file_list)) {
    mydataFrame = readLines(file_list[i])
    for (line in mydataFrame) {
        elems <- unlist(strsplit(line, split = "\\\\"))
        value <- as.numeric(str_extract(elems[2], "[+|-][0-9]*\\.?[0-9]*"))
    }
}
```

First, the string is split over `\`, and the second field is ASF with its associated value. Then, you can use str_extract to extract the number part now.

Answer (score 0):

Edited to show full code

As you are looping over a number of files, you need to do something to prevent value being overwritten in each loop. One option is use a list. If you want the result as one vector you could use `c` instead.

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
# Initialise empty list
value <- list()
for (i in 1:length(file_list)) {
  mydataFrame = readLines(file_list[i])
  value[[i]] <- as.numeric(sub(".*ASF=(-[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+).*$","\\1",mydataFrame))
}
```

Note you don't need to call `grep` then `sub`. Just `sub`.

I tested this on a folder containing two text files

```
> value
[[1]]
[1] -873.1421 -823.1421 -813.1421

[[2]]
[1] -573.1421 -223.1421 -713.1421
```